# Bind user control dependency properties in MVVM style Windows Phone app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, wpf-controls, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm having some issues with binding some custom controls in a Windows Phone app right now. Usually this is never an issue but apparently my mind can't comprehend this today.

So I'm doing an MVVM style setup which is good. I have my page with a view and also a viewmodel. Now on a WebClient callback I assign the dataContext of my view to the list of models in my ViewModel, nice and simple thus far...now in my view I created a ListBox with a custom control in the datatemplate which is basically a cell in the list. I once again set my user controls dataContext to binding, and binding all the models values to the regular UI elements works no problem.

Here's a sample:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Image Source="{Binding SmallPath}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <StackPanel Margin="12,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock x:Name="MemberId_TextBlock" Text="{Binding MemberId}" FontSize="28"
                           Margin="0,-8,0,0"
                           Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,-11,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DaysReported}" FontSize="42"
                               Margin="0,0,0,0"
                               Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="days" FontSize="24"
                               Margin="3,19,0,0"
                               Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

That's in my user control, and here's the the view where the usercontrol is housed:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <ListBox Name="TopSpotter_ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding MemberId}"/>-->
                    <controls:TopSpotterItemControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>
                    <Grid Height="18"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Now this is good enough but what I want to do in my view is set data from my model like Booleans that determine whether or not I should show certain Grids etc. So if I try to set a dependency property explicitly in my control it fires and will run logic in the Getter/Setters for instance. HOWEVER if I try to set these custom objects from a binding source it won't actually set.

Here's what works:

```
<controls:TopSpotterItemControl ChampVisibility="True">
```

This way will trigger the ChampVisibility property and then in the code behind of the user control I can set visibilities.

Here's what fails but I want to work:

```
<controls:TopSpotterItemControl ChampVisibility="{Binding IsChamp">
```

In addition I can still set the DataContext to {Binding} and the result will be unchanged.

In this scenario IsChamp is part of my model that I would like to bind to this user control which I guess comes from the dataContext being set on the view from the viewModel. I'm not sure what I can do to get this so the bindings work etc. without having to set custom properties.

Finally, here's my user control:

```
public partial class TopSpotterItemControl : UserControl
{
    public string MemberId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.MemberId_TextBlock.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.MemberId_TextBlock.Text = value;
        }
    }

    public bool ChampVisibility {
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                this.Champ_Grid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MemberNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MemberId", typeof(string), typeof(TopSpotterItemControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChampVisibilityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ChampVisibility", typeof(bool), typeof(TopSpotterItemControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public TopSpotterItemControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Bit long winded and I hope I made things on the issue clear. My one major hang up so far, and I'd like to abstract as much control as I can to the user control via dependency properties explicitly set in xaml, rather than setting up binding in its xaml that depend on the knowledge of a model. Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you missing a Getter for ChampVisibility? Try adding it and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Hey Justin, I don't believe that is the issue, however I tried it anyway to no avail. It still seems to do with when binding is involved not when it's explicitly set.

Answer (score 1):

Your DependencyProperty is badly formed. (I also don't see Champ_Grid defined in your class or XAML, but I assume that is an ommission)

Setting ChampVisibility = true in code works because it is unrelated to the DependencyProperty.

You can tell easily because the default value for your DP is invalid. It will compile, but the instance constructor will through an exception if it is ever invoked.

> new PropertyMetadata(null)

bool = null = exception

If you call GetValue(TopSpotterItemControl.ChampVisibilityProperty) from somewhere you can confirm all of the above.

You should make changes to instance fields in the property changed handler and declare the property like the following, it will work:
Note that the property has to change (not just be set) for the event to be raised.

```
public bool ChampVisibility
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(ChampVisibilityProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ChampVisibilityProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ChampVisibilityProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ChampVisibility ", typeof(bool), typeof(TopSpotterItemControl), new PropertyMetadata(true, (s, e) =>
{
    TopSpotterItemControl instance = s as TopSpotterItemControl;
    instance.Champ_Grid.Visibility = instance.ChampVisibility ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible : System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}));
```

Incidentally, your MemberId DependencyProperty is also completely wrong and cannot work.

Note:
The Binding on your TextBox works, because it is binding to the DataContext (your model), so it probably shows the right value.
The Dependency property in your UserControl will never be set though.

Use the propdp code-snippet in Visual Studio so you dont have to concern yourself with the complexities of Dependency Property declaration.

Also [check this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms752914.aspx) for more info about Dependency Properties